# solving system of linear equations:

Tags: linear-algebra

(i) Solve the above system of linear equations using Gauss-Jordon Elimination.
and (ii) For the above systems, find the values of x, y, and z such that xy = 20.

to $ \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & -2 &1 = -6 \\
     2 & -3&0 = -7\\
     -1 & 3 & -3 =11\\
     \end{bmatrix}$,
when I do this i get stuck at to $ \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & -2 &1 = -6 \\
     0 & 1&-2 = 5\\
     0 & 0 & 0 =-10\\
     \end{bmatrix}$,
Is this equation is inconsistent?

Comment: What linear system?

Comment: the linear equation is  (\begin{array}{c c c|c}1x-2y+z =-6 \\
2x-3y=-7\\
-x+3y-3z=11\\
\end{array}

Comment: @rubik since the last row are all zeros so this is an inconsistent equation and thus the value for x and y does not exist?

Comment: @shidiv You should comment under my answer, otherwise I don't get notified. On the contrary, since the last row is null that means that there is an infinite number of solutions. In general, a linear system $AX = B$ has $\infty^{n - p}$ solutions, where $n$ is the number of variables and $p = \operatorname{rank}(A)$. This is a consequence of the [Rouché-Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

You simply did a mistake computing the new rows. Applying the transformations
$$\begin{align*}R_2 &= R_2 - 2R_1\\
R_3 &= R_3 + R_1\end{align*}$$
we get
$$\left(\begin{array}{c c c|c}1 & -2 & 1 & -6\\
2 & -3 & 0 & -7\\
-1 & 3 & -3 & 11\\
\end{array}\right) \longrightarrow \left(\begin{array}{c c c|c}1 & -2 & 1 & -6\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 5\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 5\\
\end{array}\right)$$
and finally,
$$\left(\begin{array}{c c c|c}1 & -2 & 1 & -6\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right)$$

As you can see there are $\infty^1$ solutions (the number $1$ indicates that there is $1$ free variable). You can get a single solution by using the second condition,
$$xy = 20.$$